# 403 CSRF errors when trying to login to Django Admin over an SSH tunnel

Tags: django, django-admin, csrf, django-csrf, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to login to the admin panel of a Django application via another server (say `123.123.123.123`). I have a ssh tunnel open like `ssh -L 3000:my.website.com:443 user@123.123.123.123`. I can then go to `https://localhost:3000/admin/login/` and see the login page for the Django admin of the server running on `my.website.com`. Whatever credentials I put in, results in a HTTP 403 'CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` error page.

I do not get this error when going directly to `my.website.com/admin/login/`. What settings might help to allow login via an SSH tunnel? I have already tried adding `'localhost'` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. The CSRF cookies are secure (only available via HTTPS, which I'm always using) and have the HTTPOnly flag set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will see that you're trying to access `my.website.com` domain and it will send back to you cookie for that domain.

But your browser is actually accessing `localhost` domain, so cookies for `my.website.com` won't be valid for it and browser won't send them back to Django server.

One way to fix it is to point `my.website.com` to 127.0.0.1 using `/etc/hosts`, change your tunnel port to 443 and connect to `my.website.com` instead.

Another approach is to set any server in between you and your django server that will rewrite cookies and other paths from one domain to another.

Comment: I added `127.0.0.1 my.website.com` to `/etc/hosts/`. Worked perfectly!